# How to enable/disable a LAN connetion as normal user in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, group-policy, non-admin, gpedit

I have a Win10 workstation and I use a non-admin account for all normal operations.

I want my account to have the right to disable my VMnet1 and VMnet8 adapters because when up, my Wi-Fi becomes unstable somehow.

I tried this [gpedit](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.NetworkConnections::NC_LanConnect) solution : User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Network->Network Connections->Ability to Enable/Disable a LAN connection , then logoff/logon but it does not work :

[image: Ability to Enable/Disable a LAN connection]

Then I noticed, it mentions `Supported on: Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 only`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need administrator permissions to enable/disable a network adapter,
and there is no workaround this limitation.

One solution might be to use a third-party product such as
[RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
to execute an elevated program while keeping secret the
administrator password itself.
The password is encrypted and is not visible to the user.
For more details see the article
[Pass the password to Runas with RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/guidance.html).

Other similar products are (without recommendation) :

- [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) (freeware)
- [Make Me Admin](https://github.com/pseymour/MakeMeAdmin/wiki/) (freeware)
- [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-4/) (freeware)
- [Runasrob](https://runasrob.com/) (commercial)
  The free version has an annoying popup window which appears randomly.

The commands to enable/disables the network adapter can be:

```
netsh interface set interface "YOUR-ADAPTER-NAME" disable
netsh interface set interface "YOUR-ADAPTER-NAME" enable
```